# JavaScript anonymous function memory allocation and garbage allocation

Tags: jquery, ajax, extjs, jslint

```
// This is a Framework Method 
function ajaxJSONType(uri, reqtype , reqJSON , callback){
    var url : uri; 

    $jq.ajax({

    url: uri,
    type: reqtype,
    data:reqJSON ,
    dataType: ResponseDataType.JSON,
    sucess: function(data){
        // do some validation on response data and call the callback function 
        callback(data);
    },

    }); 
}
```

Every Developer calling this method from their code something like this

First Approach:

```
function MyMethod(){
       var reqdata = {};
       ajaxJSONType(serviceUri , ReqType.POST,function(responsedata){

                // Here some processing on the response will occur 

           });
}
```

Here the callback method is an anonymous  function used to parse the response and process.

Second Approach :

```
function MyMethod(){
    var reqdata = {};
    ajaxJSONType(serviceUri , ReqType.POST,myCallbackFun);
}


function  myCallbackFun(responsedata){

     // Here some processing on the response will occur  

}
```

My Question :

IF the MyMethod will be called more than 1000 Times in a short time period ..

```
Will it good to have the anonymous function or named function ? 

The First approch will create function object 1000 times ?

 I saw in JSLINT , we should not create anonymous function inside a loop.    
  here though we dont have any loop the MyMethod will be called many times by other events. So it is also like a Loop.
```

I am using the IE 9 browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I saw in JSLINT , we should not create anonymous function inside a loop.

The [reason for the warning](http://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop) in JSLint is the potential misunderstanding of the closure created by the function within the loop. It's not related to performance.

> Will it good to have the anonymous function or named function ?

As you've mentioned, by passing a function expression directly into the call the engine is having to create a new copy of that function every time you call `MyMethod`. For that reason, it is likely preferable in this case to go with the function declaration. However, don't get caught up in premature optimisations... you're unlikely to notice any real performance increase.

Comment: HI James.. Thanks for your information.

Even if the  anonymous function created 1000 times it wont have any performance issue ?

How about the Memory allocation and Garbage collection?

Comment: The function should be garbage collected once it's completed execution. Obviously, if the function is allocated many times in quick succession this will have an impact on performance. It's just unlikely to have a *visible* impact.